# How to yank text from the kill-ing and instert it at the cursor location in another terminal window?

Tags: bash, clipboard, konsole, kde5

Is it possible to copy a text from one terminal and input it into another without selecting it?

More precisely, within the same terminal window, I can kill the text line by `CTRL-U` and then yank the killed line by `CTRL-Y`. However, `CTRL-Y` doesn't seem to work when trying within another terminal window or even to another terminal tab.

I'm using bash 5.1.16, Konosle terminal in a KDE desktop environment (plasma 5.27.6) in Arch Linux x86_64.

Comment: duplicate of https://superuser.com/q/1796201/4714

Comment: Please [do not cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/355310).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In modern `bash` with default configuration, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Y</kbd> are bound to readline library functions `unix-line-discard` and `yank`, respectively. In other words, these operations are handled by `bash` itself, not by Konsole.

The shell has no awareness of other terminal windows or tabs, so it cannot pass the killed text to them. For that, you would need a shell that is truly integrated to the windowing system, not one that lives within a terminal emulator.

If the `bind-tty-special-chars` readline variable was set to Off, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd> would fall back to the TTY/PTY driver's `kill` character functionality (see `stty -a` and `man termios`), which would not be undoable by the shell - and as each terminal tab is implemented using a separate PTY device, the problem would be the same at that layer too.

So the answer must be: using the normal `bash` shell, copying text from one terminal session to another (without selecting the copied text using some external mechanism that can span multiple PTYs, like GUI terminal emulators, `screen` or `tmux`) is not possible.